# Swift App Crashing after moving to view controller from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am using moving to a new view controller from app delegate using this code I found from somewhere on stack overflow

```
    func changeRootViewController(with identifier:String!) {
    let storyboard = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard
    let desiredViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier);

    let snapshot:UIView = (self.window?.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true))!
    desiredViewController?.view.addSubview(snapshot);

    self.window?.rootViewController = desiredViewController;

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {() in
        snapshot.layer.opacity = 0;
        snapshot.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
    }, completion: {
        (value: Bool) in
        snapshot.removeFromSuperview();
    });
}
```

It works fine and I am able to move to a new view controller with the animation ( **WHICH IS REQUIRED** ). But as soon as I move to some other app and return back, the app crashes with error.

> Cannot snapshot view (; layer =
>   >) with afterScreenUpdates:NO, because the
>   view is not in a window. Use afterScreenUpdates:YES. fatal error:
>   unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The other code I have for opening a view controller from AppDelegate

```
func showViewController(id: String){
    let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: id) as UIViewController
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

It works perfectly but when tried to add animation the animation doesn't work. So kindly help in resolving these issues.

Comment: Don't get me wrong here one good learning is "Don't just copy the code from StackOverflow" - Instead try to understand it and implement by your own. I did the same mistake before. 

The reason why it is crashing is that you are taking a snapshot of the current window and using it for animation. When you open the app from background `self.window` might be nil so you can not actually take a snapshot from it. I would suggest to find a different way to add your animation when opening the app

Comment: https://www.gitbook.com/book/tra38/essential-copying-and-pasting-from-stack-overflow/details

Comment: just check values needed at desiredViewController exist while you reach from appdelgate ?

Comment: I agree with you @Bluewings. I am still in swift learning phase so I needed to do that quickly, hence I tried the code directly. Thanks for the comment tough will surely look into that snapshot thing you mentioned.

Comment: Do you try to get a smooth transition from launch screen to your first view controller? How about a different approach? Your first view controller can initially display the image of the launch screen, and than transit to the actual view. This wouldn't relay on undocumented features before the view controller is launched from the app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with animation like ?

```
UIView.transition(with: appDel.window!,
              duration: 0.25,
               options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
            animations: { appDel.window?.rootViewController = vc } ,
            completion: nil)
```